# pass value if using front camera with intent method

Tags: android

i want to check if photo is taken with front camera with intent method.

below is code for run the camera

```
public void runCamera(){
    String fileName = "temp.jpg";

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, fileName);

    mCapturedImageURI = getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);

    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mCapturedImageURI);
    startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, RESULT_CAMERA);
}
```

then below is activity result to process the taken image.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
...
case RESULT_CAMERA:
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK && mCapturedImageURI!=null){
                String[] projection = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
                Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(mCapturedImageURI, projection, null, null, null);
                String filePath;
                if (cursor != null) {
                    cursor.moveToFirst();
                    int column_index_data = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
                    filePath = cursor.getString(column_index_data);
                }
                else
                    filePath = data.getData().getPath();
                GeneralizeImage mGI = new GeneralizeImage(this,filePath);
                //getOrientationImage();
                uploadFileToServer(mGI.Convert());
                cursor.close();
            }
            else{
                Toast.makeText(this, "Try Again", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            break;
```

i appreciate any help from you guys, thanks.

Comment: What errors are you facing?

Comment: @JayminPanchal theres no errors here, but i want to know how to check if taken photo is using front camera or read camera. because if i using front camera, the image always flipped horizontally. sorry for my unclear explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass parameter in your intent to open front camera.

Try this

```
takePictureIntent.putExtra("android.intent.extras.CAMERA_FACING", 1);
```

Comment: It does not work. Could you send us the source?